# Optimization issue, Nonlinear: automatic analytical Jacobian/Hessian from objective and constraints in R?

Tags: r, automatic-differentiation

In R, is it possible to find the Jacobian/Hessian/sparsity pattern analytically when you provide just the objective function and constraints for an optimization problem?

AMPL does this, and from what I hear even MATLAB can do this, but I don't know if you need Knitro for this.

However, all the optimization tools for R (such as nloptr) seem to require **me** to enter the gradient and Hessian myself, which is very difficult since I am working with a complex model.

Comment: There is a `hessian` parameter in optim.  Is this not what you want?

Comment: The hessian is computed numerically which is a problem for the type of work I am doing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is called [automatic differentiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_differentiation). Sadly, it looks like to me it is not available in R.

There were [attempts 5 years ago](http://www.autodiff.org/Docs/euroad/Eighth%20EuroAd%20Workshop%20-%20Finlay%20Scott%20-%20AD%20in%20R.pdf) to implement it but my short investigation indicates that these attempts died out.

There is a fairly recent R package ([Automatic Differentiation Model Builder](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/PBSadmb/index.html)) but it is unclear to me how to use it, or how to apply this to your situation. (I don't use R myself, that's why I don't know.)

Comment: I just wrote an AD package in R: https://github.com/shabbychef/madness . Submit an issue if you have any.

Comment: Note for people reading this, apparently Julia (the language) can do this.  I will begin the switch partly for this

Comment: @robertevansanders Several automatic differentiation libraries exist in other languages, but the question specifically asked for a solution in R. Apparently the above linked shabbychef / madness R package can do this too but it did not exist in 2014 when I wrote my answer.

Answer (score 2):

**1)** The default Nelder Mead method in `optim` does not need derivatives and does not compute them internally either.

**2)** `D`, `deriv` and related R functions (see `?deriv`) can compute simple symbolic derivatives.

**3)** The [Ryacas package](http://ryacas.googlecode.com) can compute symbolic derivatives.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a basic package for Automatic Differentation in R, called [madness](https://github.com/shabbychef/madness). While it is primarily designed for the multivariate delta method, it should also be usable for computing gradients automatically. An example usage:

```
require(madness)

# the 'fit' is the Frobenius norm of Y - L*R
# with a penalty for strongly negative R.
compute_fit <- function(R,L,Y) {
    Rmad <- madness(R)
    Err <- Y - L %*% Rmad
    penalty <- sum(exp(-0.1 * Rmad))
    fit <- norm(Err,'f') + penalty
}

set.seed(1234)
R <- array(runif(5*20),dim=c(5,20))
L <- array(runif(1000*5),dim=c(1000,5))
Y <- array(runif(1000*20),dim=c(1000,20))
ftv <- compute_fit(R,L,Y)
show(ftv)
show(val(ftv))
show(dvdx(ftv))
```

I get back the following:

```
class: madness 
        d (norm((numeric - (numeric  %*% R)), 'f') + (sum(exp((numeric * R)), na.rm=FALSE) + numeric))
 calc: ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
                                                      d R
  val: 207.6 ...
 dvdx: 4.214 4.293 4.493 4.422 4.672 2.899 2.222 2.565 2.854 2.718 4.499 4.055 4.161 4.473 4.069 2.467 1.918 2.008 1.874 1.942 0.2713 0.2199 0.135 0.03017 0.1877 5.442 4.81
1 5.472 5.251 4.674 1.933 1.62 1.79 1.902 1.665 5.232 4.435 4.789 5.183 5.084 3.602 3.477 3.419 3.592 3.376 4.109 3.937 4.017 3.816 4.2 1.776 1.784 2.17 1.975 1.699 4.365 4
.09 4.475 3.964 4.506 1.745 1.042 1.349 1.084 1.237 3.1 2.575 2.887 2.524 2.902 2.055 2.441 1.959 2.467 1.985 2.494 2.223 2.124 2.275 2.546 3.497 2.961 2.897 3.111 2.9 4.44
2 3.752 3.939 3.694 4.326 0.9582 1.4 0.8971 0.8756 0.9019 2.399 2.084 2.005 2.154 2.491 ...
 varx:  ...

      [,1]
[1,] 207.6

      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]  [,6]  [,7]  [,8]  [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15] [,16] [,17] [,18] [,19] [,20]  [,21]  [,22] [,23]   [,24]  [,25] [,26] [,27]
[1,] 4.214 4.293 4.493 4.422 4.672 2.899 2.222 2.565 2.854 2.718 4.499 4.055 4.161 4.473 4.069 2.467 1.918 2.008 1.874 1.942 0.2713 0.2199 0.135 0.03017 0.1877 5.442 4.811
     [,28] [,29] [,30] [,31] [,32] [,33] [,34] [,35] [,36] [,37] [,38] [,39] [,40] [,41] [,42] [,43] [,44] [,45] [,46] [,47] [,48] [,49] [,50] [,51] [,52] [,53] [,54]
[1,] 5.472 5.251 4.674 1.933  1.62  1.79 1.902 1.665 5.232 4.435 4.789 5.183 5.084 3.602 3.477 3.419 3.592 3.376 4.109 3.937 4.017 3.816   4.2 1.776 1.784  2.17 1.975
     [,55] [,56] [,57] [,58] [,59] [,60] [,61] [,62] [,63] [,64] [,65] [,66] [,67] [,68] [,69] [,70] [,71] [,72] [,73] [,74] [,75] [,76] [,77] [,78] [,79] [,80] [,81]
[1,] 1.699 4.365  4.09 4.475 3.964 4.506 1.745 1.042 1.349 1.084 1.237   3.1 2.575 2.887 2.524 2.902 2.055 2.441 1.959 2.467 1.985 2.494 2.223 2.124 2.275 2.546 3.497
     [,82] [,83] [,84] [,85] [,86] [,87] [,88] [,89] [,90]  [,91] [,92]  [,93]  [,94]  [,95] [,96] [,97] [,98] [,99] [,100]
[1,] 2.961 2.897 3.111   2.9 4.442 3.752 3.939 3.694 4.326 0.9582   1.4 0.8971 0.8756 0.9019 2.399 2.084 2.005 2.154  2.491
```

Note that the derivative is the derivative of the scalar with respect to a 5 x 20 matrix, but is flattened here to a vector. (Unfortunately a row vector.)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `solnp`, package `Rsolnp`. It is a nonlinear programming solver which does not require analytical Jacobian or Hessian:

```
min f(x)
s.t. g(x) = 0
l[h] <= h(x) <= u[h]
l[x] <= x <= u[x]
```

Comment: Do you know offhand if it computes the Jacobian and Hessian numerically? Or is it able to understand the optimization problem the way a mathematical programming language would and find analytical derivatives it can use?

Comment: It uses finite differences type of numerical approximation, of course. The latter (symbolic differentiation) is also [available](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4775/symbolic-computation-in-r) in R, by the way.

Comment: Finite differences is a big problem in the kind of work I am doing.  The computational burden is quite high and I need to provide analytical derivatives to the solver if it is to finish in a reasonable amount of time.  Are you saying I have to always program the derivatves myself in R?  (Unlike MATLAB and AMPL?)

Comment: I can't say, always; in most cases, yes. Here's a [comprehensive list](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Optimization.html), you may find something useful there. Please let me know if your search is successful.